# How to test the connection to RabbitMQ Server?

Tags: cmd, rabbitmq, amqp

I have the following problem: 
I need to test connection to **RabbitMQ Server** which operates on **AMQ Protocol**, and i need to do it using CMD or something similar, so i can execute the command from script. I don't know if it's possible,the only thing that I found on internet was testing connection through HTTP, and it doesn't work for me.So shortly, **I need cmd command that tests connection to RabbitMQ server which uses AMQP.**

I hope that someone understands what is my problem, maybe i didn't described it good.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at `Get-RabbitMQConnection` from https://github.com/mariuszwojcik/RabbitMQTools? A modern-day machine running cmd.exe cam also have (probably already has) powershell.exe on it.

Comment: The post that you provided here actually made a little progress, because i didn't know about this repository,but still this is not really the solution for my problem.

Comment: In a cmd.exe shell, would the command `powershell -NoProfile -Command "Get-RabbitMQConnection ..."` identify if RabbitMQ is working?

Comment: After trying to execute the command that you provided here, I get this error `Get-RabbitMQConnection : The term 'Get-RabbitMQConnection' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-RabbitMQConnection
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-RabbitMQConnection:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`

Comment: Did you install `RabbitMQTools`? See the `Getting Started` section on that page.

Comment: I find out what was the problem, and its kinda silly. You need to establish connection first, but its kinda tricky to do on local machine, simply said you need to simulate communication between ,in this case, two scripts.Then its easy to list the connections with command  `rabbitmqctl list_connections`. And i've done it without any of those RabbitMQTools that you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find out what the problem was, and it's kinda silly. You need to establish connection first, but it's kinda tricky to do on local machine. Simply said, you need to simulate communication between, in this case, two scripts. Then, it's easy to list the connections with command:

```
rabbitmqctl list_connections
```

Comment: Glad to hear you found an answer. `RabbitMQTools` might still be useful.

Answer (score 11):

I found another way to verify basic tcp connectivity using just netcat/telnet.

```bash
nc hostname 5672
```

OR

```bash
telnet hostname 5672
```

Type `HELO` and hit enter 4 times.

You should see a response of `AMQP`.

example:

```bash
> nc rabbitserver 5672
HELO



AMQP
```

The other tools mentioned here would verify deeper compatibility between the client and server as well as validate other protocols. If you simply need to make sure that port 5672 is open in the firewall between the client and server then this basic test should be enough.

Comment: OMG... This needs to be part of the rabbitmq documentation! You can't find this anywhere. One liner in case anyone is interested `printf "HELO\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" | nc rabbit-server-ip-or-domain 5672`

Comment: Or better yet... just returns `printf "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" | nc rabbit-server-ip-or-domain 5672`

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'd call a full stack testing script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Check connection to the RabbitMQ server

# import parser for command-line options
import argparse
# import a pure-Python implementation of the AMQP 0-9-1 
import pika
import ssl

# define and parse command-line options
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Check connection to RabbitMQ server')
parser.add_argument('--server', required=True, help='Define RabbitMQ server')
parser.add_argument('--virtual_host', default='/', help='Define virtual host')
parser.add_argument('--ssl', action='store_true', help='Enable SSL (default: %(default)s)')
parser.add_argument('--port', type=int, default=5672, help='Define port (default: %(default)s)')
parser.add_argument('--username', default='guest', help='Define username (default: %(default)s)')
parser.add_argument('--password', default='guest', help='Define password (default: %(default)s)')
args = vars(parser.parse_args())

# set amqp credentials
credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(args['username'], args['password'])

if args['ssl']:
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    ssl_options = pika.SSLOptions(context, args['server'])
else:
    ssl_options = None

parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(host=args['server'], port=args['port'], virtual_host=args['virtual_host'], credentials=credentials, ssl_options=ssl_options)

# try to establish connection and check its status
try:
  connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
  if connection.is_open:
    print('OK')
    connection.close()
    exit(0)
except Exception as error:
  print('Error:', error.__class__.__name__)
  exit(1)
```

Original IDEA and script: https://sleeplessbeastie.eu/2017/07/10/how-to-check-connection-to-the-rabbitmq-message-broker/

I just adjusted the above script to work with newer "pika" ssl parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Following up on [Dan Wilson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76176225/619961)'s answer, I threw together a check script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

: ${RMQHOST:="localhost"}
: ${RMQPORT:="5672"}

check_rabbitmq() {
        exec 3>&- 3<>/dev/tcp/${RMQHOST}/${RMQPORT} || return 1
        printf '%s\n\n\n\n' "HELO" >&3 || return 1
        local ret=$(tr -d '\0' <&3 || return 1)
        [[ x"${ret}" =~ x"AMQP" ]] && return 0 || return 1
} 2>/dev/null

check_rabbitmq && echo OK || echo NOK
```